# Sharepoint 2013 - How to add SAVE, SUBMIT and CANCEL buttons to forms

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, custom-list, submit

How to add SAVE, SUBMIT and CANCEL buttons to custom form.
I have posted a similar question but with a different approach but I do want to know if this is possible to ADD another button and function to a custom form?

Comment: Have You created Custom List Forms? You want to implement buttons in Add/Edit or View Form of List?

Comment: In the NewForm.aspx and the EditForm.aspx pages